# Unable to assign table name in SQLite Database dynanmically

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
    Code :

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RegistrationPage var = new RegistrationPage();
                    DATABASE_TABLE =  var.username.getText().toString();

                    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_FIRSTNAME
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MIDDLENAME
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MAIL_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_COUNTRY + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ");");
```

The above code represents the method from DBAdapter class where i initialize and do all the activities in database.

I have 3 activities

1. SignIn
2. Register
3. View

SignIn : Not concentrating on it as of now.

Register : In this page, i get the details of the user including the USERNAME WHICH SHOULD SET AS THE NAME FOR THE TABLE IN MY DATABASE. Then i open it and insert all the data into the database.

**NOTE : Inserting the data doesn't work while i assign the table name dynamically but if i hardcode the table name then it works like a charm**

View : While viewing, i need to open the database first which would require the table name that i assigned in the previous activity but it says null pointer exception while moving to this activity and force closes my application.

Help me guys. I am newbie and desperate about this project.

Comment: I had to get the instance of RegistrationPage in all the methods to access the DATABASE_TABLE name. Methods like onCreate(),onUpdate(),onInsert() and so on.

Comment: Why don't you use a single "Users" table, with the user name as an extra column?

Comment: @CL, Thats what i am going to do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to store the table name in some storage i.e: `SharedPreferences` and use it for creating , fetching, inserting, updating your table.

Comment: You mean that i get the username and assign it to shared preference and then use it across all the meethods ??

Comment: yes, this is the better way because if you are using database its obvious that your application will use the database in future also when you close the application and come back to use it!

Comment: Thanks pal. Much appreciated. Will try that and get back to ya !!

Comment: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
  String et_string = sp.getString("database_tabel",var.username.getText().toString()); Will this work ?

Comment: You should [check out](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html) how to insert and fetch data from SharedPreferences :-)